# QTimeEdit, change only hours?

Tags: qt, qt5, qdatetime

In my application I have a QTimeEdit, in which I only want to edit the hours. Is it possible to do that? (Disable editing of minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override [`void QDateTimeEdit::stepBy(int steps)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#stepBy) to add/remove hours only.

Though the Qt code seems a bit complicated for that task : https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qdatetimeedit.cpp.html#_ZN13QDateTimeEdit6stepByEi

Comment: Oh, yep, it seems really complicated...I think I will look for another solution or let it be possible to edit hours and minutes :D. Nevertheless, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Actually the code is complicated because it handles date and time and different options of the input. But if you want some clear and less flexible behaviour like : step-up adds 1h, step-down removes 1h, it might be less complicated, sadly I have no time to try to make an example at the moment

Comment: At the moment it is not that bad, wenn I can set the minutes too. Maybe I will have a look at this at a later time :)